# How to set size of tiled drawables

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a table that is supposed to have checkerboard background. For that, I use tiled drawables like so:

```
TiledDrawable boardBg;
boardBg = new TiledDrawable(menuSkin.getTiledDrawable("boardBg"));
boardTable.setBackground(boardBg);
```

Then each tile has the size the drawable has by defualt, say 64px. What do I have to do so that each tile is larger? I tried

```
boardBg.setMinWidth(500);
boardBg.setMinHeight(500);
```

but that doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The TiledDrawable class doesn't support scaling i made a class that extends TiledDrawable and can be scaled. Preferable you dont want to scale down more than 0.1 it will be a performance hog (depending on the size of the texture) at that scale. So use with caution when scaling down. Note i didnt account for when the scale is set to zero so maybe create a method setScale where it throws an error when that happens. Use the ScaledTiledDrawable like this:

```
ScaledTiledDrawable scaledTiledDrawable = new ScaledTiledDrawable( new TextureRegion( texture ) );
scaledTiledDrawable.getScale().set( 0.5f, 0.5f );
```

Here is the class:

```
public class ScaledTiledDrawable extends TiledDrawable {

    private Vector2 scale = new Vector2();
    private Affine2 transform = new Affine2();
    private Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4();
    private Matrix4 oldMatrix = new Matrix4();

    public ScaledTiledDrawable() {

        super();
    }

    public ScaledTiledDrawable( TextureRegion region ) {

        super( region );
    }

    public ScaledTiledDrawable( TextureRegionDrawable drawable ){

        super( drawable );
    }

    public Vector2 getScale() {

        return scale;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw( Batch batch, float x, float y, float width, float height ) {

        oldMatrix.set( batch.getTransformMatrix() );
        matrix.set( transform.setToTrnScl( x, y, scale.x, scale.y ) );

        batch.setTransformMatrix( matrix );

        super.draw( batch, 0, 0, width / scale.x, height / scale.y );

        batch.setTransformMatrix( oldMatrix );
    }
}
```